# What's the difference between the terms "muscle" and "muscle organ"?

Tags: human-anatomy, terminology, anatomy

Foundational Model of Anatomy distinguishes between [Muscle organ](http://purl.org/sig/ont/fma/fma5022) and [Muscle](http://purl.org/sig/ont/fma/fma30316). What's the difference between the two?

Comment: Your links do not work. If there is relevant info at either link, please quote it as necessary in your post. Also, please clarify what you are referring to regarding "Foundational Model of Anatomy". If this is a book, please include a more complete citation (i.e., include authors, year, edition, publisher). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The word "muscle" is applied to both the [organ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organ_(anatomy)) and to the [tissue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tissue_(biology)).

- There are 3 types of muscle tissue: [skeletal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_muscle), [smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_muscle), and [cardiac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardiac_muscle).

Below is a decent quote from [SEER](https://training.seer.cancer.gov/anatomy/muscular/structure.html) explaining this (my emphasis added):

> A whole **skeletal *muscle*** is considered an *organ* of the muscular system. Each organ or muscle consists of **skeletal *muscle* tissue**, connective tissue, nerve tissue, and blood or vascular tissue

If the word "muscle" is used on its own (i.e., without specifying "muscle *tissue*" or "*skeletal* muscle"), it is typically referring to the whole skeletal muscle organ.

- Examples: chest muscles (pectoralis muscles), thigh muscles (quadriceps and hamstrings), etc.

---

Note: the word "bone" is used in a very similar manner.

- "Bone" can refer to the [entire organ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bone) (e.g., femur) or to one of the [two recognized bone tissue types](https://training.seer.cancer.gov/anatomy/skeletal/tissue.html) ([compact bone](https://biologydictionary.net/compact-bone) and [spongy bone](https://www.britannica.com/science/cancellous-bone)).

Answer (score -1):

In the context you state, seemingly nothing. "Muscle" is listed as a homonym of "Muscle organ". So it seems, for the sake of the website you like to, there is no difference (unless they are using homonym differently).